# I purchased new washer and dryer and the breakers for them are tripping after using dryer

Tags: electrical-panel

The dryer is causing the breakers to trip after 5 minutes of use.  Specially if I put too much clothes.  Can I replace them with 30 amp breakers to avoid this?

Comment: What amperage are they now? Does your dryer manual have a recommended breaker size?

Comment: You can never just increase the breaker size.  Breaker size is tied to the wire size that runs through the walls, and you can't make one bigger without also make the other bigger (replacing all the wiring).

Comment: Please confirm.  Are there seperate breakers for washer and dryer?  Please take a photo of them and add it to your question.

Comment: Is this an electric or gas dryer?   That is to say, if you look at the electric plug on the dryer, is it the same plug as your PC uses, or is it a larger, sorta weird plug that takes more effort to plug in?

Answer (score 3):

Up-sizing the breaker will only work if the right size wires are used. Adding a larger breaker will allow it more breathing room so as not to trip, but if the wires aren't sized right then it'll just burn them up (without tripping) and lead to a fire hazard.

You'd want to have #10 wires ran for a 30A breaker. As long as they are, there'll be no problem.

I'll say though, typically a dryer uses a 30A breaker to begin with and it's odd that Both breakers are tripping when the dryer runs. Your washer circuit should have no influence from the dryer's.

Comment: To clarify, upsizing the breaker will actually *work*, regardless of the wire size, and probably won't "burn up" the wire itself. However; if the wire isn't big enough you absolutely ***will*** create a fire hazard. So don't upsize the breaker on small wire and believe you've solved the problem. The wire will get hot enough to start a fire. You absolutely shouldn't put a 30A breaker on wire any smaller than #10 AWG.

Comment: _"You'd want to have #10 wires ran for a 30A breaker. As long as they are, they'll be no problem."_ ...... If it is a gas dryer in North America this is most likely NOT an option. Even with #10 wire, you are NOT allowed to have a typical 15 or 20 amp 120V receptacle on a 30A circuit.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey Didn't consider a gas dryer. My answer applies directly to electric only.

Answer (score 0):

Check the manual, but I'd take it back or call for warranty service. It appears the motor is bad. There shouldn't be any change even if it's stuffed with dripping clothes.